# Fastest way to search thousands of keywords in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, keyword

I want to scan a web page for existence of keywords from my dictionary. 
There are already asked questions about this to emphasize the keywords. However my dictionary will be huge eg 50.000 words. What is the best way to do it?
Also I want to search the website for variations of my library. For example my library contains gene names such as p53. I want to search the site for "p53", "p53 protein" , "induction of p53", "inhibits p53" "phosphorylates p53". How can I do this? What should be the fastest way

Or think that I have 2 lists

```
   List1                List2
   ------              -------    
   inhibits              p21
   induces               p53 
   phosphorylates        Akt
   decreases             Braf
                         cMyc
```

I want it tobe able to search combinations of List1 and 2.

```
Such as 
"inhibits cMyc" 
"phoshorylates p21"
```

This means for this example it needs to search for 4 X 5=20  keywords.
But orginally it will be something like 200 X 50000 = 1.000.000 search term.

Comment: Is there a reason that this must be done client-side?  It would be a lot more suited to server-side, say when getting the data from a presumed database?

Comment: Is the intention to run this against your own pages, or against any random page from the web?

Comment: Do you want to search a **site** or a **page**? Both terms are used in the OP, more or less interchageably. The strategy for a site would use server programming, for a page could use either but probably the server is best.

Comment: It doesnt matter for me wether in client or server... It will be run against a random page from the web. I want to search a single html page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the dictionary must be indexed. Then, the page content should also be indexed and matches found for the dictionary. Then the instances in the page should be dealt with (e.g. highlighted, linked to definitions, etc.).

The above should be done on the server unless you want to run it in a browser on random web pages, say as a Greasemonkey script. I don't think a well indexed 50,000 item dictionary will faze a reasonably modern browser on an average PC, even for pages with several thousand words.

#### Edit

If you have two lists, then index the words on the page (e.g. a very simple one is to create a sorted, unique list with a key to the first A, first B, etc.). Use the short list to search for matching words.

Use the first set of word matches and find them in the page, get the preceding word to see if it matches a word in the second list. Do the same with the following word. A simple binary lookup in a 50,000 word list never needs more than 16 lookups. Using an alphabetic index for the first lookup, then binary, should cut it to probably 5 or 6 lookups per original match.

You can also use an object instead of an indexed list and use `if (word in wordList)`, which will also be very fast (remember to include a hasOwnProperty test).

If you are only concerned with using a modern browser, check out webworkers and [web storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)

Comment: How can we index the page content. Because we are going to search combinations of two lists. So search is not on words but actually on sentences.

Comment: Indexes are created based on how you want to search. If you are looking for pairs, then index words in pairs (or threes or whatever) or link each indexed word to its place in the page so if you match the word you can find it in the document quickly and see if the following word matches too.

Answer (score 0):

Try may be it will help you

http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/javascript/highlight-words-in-text-with-jquery/

You have to prepare your patterns like this ( example to get idea)

```
string keywords = "Cat, rabbit, dog,hound, fox";
 Regex r = new Regex(@", ?");
keywords = "(" + r.Replace(keywords, @"|") + ")";
```

Comment: Could you just a bit explain me the code that you send to me?